# What is the difference in listening on "0.0.0.0:80" and ":80"?

Tags: http, go, port

When we use [`http.ListenAndServe`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe), what is the difference between:

```
http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:80", nil)
```

and

```
http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
```

? Wouldn't both versions listen on all interfaces on port `80`?

Comment: Possibly `"0.0.0.0:80"` just binds on ipv4 interface?

Comment: Seems you're right but on Linux ( which I haven't mentioned that I use it) it's not obvious because of `bindv6only` option (described here in SO answer https://serverfault.com/a/39561/78427). Basically on most distributions `bindv6only` is 0 therefore if make a socket to listen on IPv6 it will also listen on IPv4

Comment: @EmilH It's a stupid design from Go that [`0.0.0.0` is v4+v6 dual-stack](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17615).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) function eventually calls [`net.Listen()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen). The documentation for `net.Listen` states that it will bind to the network provided to it:

> For TCP networks, if the host in the address parameter is empty or a literal unspecified IP address, Listen listens on all available unicast and anycast IP addresses of the local system. To only use IPv4, use network "tcp4".

However, looking at the source for [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=83053:83087#L2702) we can see that it specifies `"tcp"` as the network and not `"tcp4"`. Therefore the call in your example code should result in identical behavior, i.e. both calls should bind to all available interfaces. However, digging further down into the golang source we end up in [`internetAddrList()`](https://golang.org/src/net/ipsock.go#L235) and we can see that it differentiates between an empty `host` value and one that has a ipv4 address specified. So golang does infact treat the ipv4 address specified as an indication to only bind on that interface.