# Dockerfile expose 80 port

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to create a simple docker container with go mod and 1.18.
my app runs in 8080 port but i wanna run in :80 port

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# pre-copy/cache go.mod for pre-downloading dependencies and only redownloading them in subsequent builds if they change
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -o server

CMD [ "./server" ]
```

so i run docker build:

```
docker build -t go-k8s .
```

and docker run

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 go-k8s:latest
```

And nothing happens :(

Comment: If you want your service to be accessible on port `80` on your host, you need `-p 80:8080`. The first argument is the host port, the second is the container port. With `-p 8080:8080`, it would be accessible on port `8080` on your host.

Comment: thankss!!!

I didn't pay attention to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As larsks says, you need to bind from the external port `80` to the internal port `8080` using the `80:8080` syntax.

Something else to consider is making sure that your app is [listening on all interfaces in your development environment.](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067160/what-is-the-difference-in-listening-on-0-0-0-080-and-80) seems at least vaguely related to yours